# R/tidyverse recognising column names

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to use pipe to filter and calculate Cohen's d statistic, but for some reason R will not recognise the column. I've tried this so many ways and can't get it to run..

```
df2 %>% filter(`Spreadsheet Row` == "Self-driving cars", `Zone Name` != "slider") %>% cohen.d(., Question,alpha=.05, data = Response)
```

Throws error: Error in cohen.d(., Question, alpha = 0.05, data = Response) :   object 'Question' not found

This is the dataframe:

```
> df2 %>% filter(`Spreadsheet Row` == "Self-driving cars", `Zone Name` != "slider")
# A tibble: 96 x 6
   `Event Index`     PID `Spreadsheet Row` Question  `Zone Name` Response
   <chr>           <dbl> <fct>             <ord>     <chr>          <dbl>
 1 17            3799252 Self-driving cars Pre-stim  core_belief        3
 2 18            3799252 Self-driving cars Pre-stim  right_wrong        2
 3 19            3799252 Self-driving cars Pre-stim  moral_issue        4
 4 20            3799252 Self-driving cars Pre-stim  just_know          3
 5 25            3799252 Self-driving cars Post-stim core_belief        4
 6 26            3799252 Self-driving cars Post-stim right_wrong        5
 7 27            3799252 Self-driving cars Post-stim moral_issue        3
 8 28            3799252 Self-driving cars Post-stim just_know          4
 9 65            3799288 Self-driving cars Pre-stim  core_belief        4
10 66            3799288 Self-driving cars Pre-stim  right_wrong        4
```

And it is clearly recognised if I use SELECT:

```
df2 %>% filter(`Spreadsheet Row` == "Self-driving cars", `Zone Name` != "slider") %>% select(Question)
# A tibble: 96 x 1
   Question 
   <ord>    
 1 Pre-stim 
 2 Pre-stim 
 3 Pre-stim 
 4 Pre-stim 
 5 Post-stim
 6 Post-stim
 7 Post-stim
 8 Post-stim
 9 Pre-stim 
10 Pre-stim 
# ... with 86 more rows
```

But as soon as I try and use the column in any way it throws the object not found error.  Driving me nuts!

```
dput(head(df2))
structure(list(`Event Index` = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11), PID = c(3800586, 
3800586, 3800586, 3800586, 3800586, 3800586), `Spreadsheet Row` = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("E-waste", "Meat", "Plastic", 
"Self-driving cars"), class = "factor"), Question = c("Familiarisation", 
"Pre-stim", "Pre-stim", "Pre-stim", "Pre-stim", "Post-stim"), 
    `Zone Name` = c("slider", "core_belief", "right_wrong", "moral_issue", 
    "just_know", "core_belief"), Response = c(6, 5, 4, 5, 3, 
    7)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), problems = structure(list(row = c(1543L, 1543L), col = c("Event Index", 
NA), expected = c("a double", "62 columns"), actual = c("END OF FILE", 
"1 columns"), file = c("'data_exp_44331-v24_task-4xn8.csv'", 
"'data_exp_44331-v24_task-4xn8.csv'")), row.names = c(NA, -2L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Using the rstatix package version works fine;

```
df2 %>% filter(`Spreadsheet Row` == "Self-driving cars", `Zone Name` != "slider") %>% rstatix::cohens_d(., Response ~ Question)
```

Comment: Which package are you using for `cohen.d`? `effsize` or `psych` or other? And you have `data = response` - what is `Response`? And can you use `dput(head(df2))` to share a sample of your data?

Comment: try `... %>% cohen.d("Question", ...)`

Comment: Hi there - the quotations marks don't work, but running cohens_d from rstatix package fixed it. Maybe the psych package version isn't pipe-able? For what it's worth I've put the dput(head) output above